# How to repeat steps on similar files in R

Tags: r, data-analysis

Currently, I'm working on a case study. My way is to look for changes between months of the past year.

I have 12 files that include data for each month with names like:

- `202201-divvy-tripdata.csv` for January
- `202202-divvy-tripdata.csv` for February
- ...
- `202212-divvy-tripdata.csv` for December

I wrote some code in R to find the sum and mean of the data for January.
My question is: How can I apply those steps on all 12 files to get the sum and mean of the data of the other 11 months?

This is my code for January:

```
data_jan <- read.csv("202201-divvy-tripdata.csv")

new_data_jan <- data_jan %>%
  select(member_casual, started_at, ended_at) %>%
  mutate(ride_length = difftime(ended_at, started_at, units = "mins"))

member_jan <- new_data_jan %>% 
  filter(member_casual == "member") %>%
  summarise(mean_member_jan = mean(ride_length),sum_member_jan = sum(ride_length))

casual_jan <- new_data_jan %>% 
  filter(member_casual == "casual") %>%
  summarise(mean_casual_jan = mean(ride_length),sum_casual_jan = sum(ride_length))
```

My current way is to copy and paste all above lines of code and replace the name of the file and variables like this for February and so on:

```
data_feb <- read.csv("202202-divvy-tripdata.csv")

new_data_feb <- data_feb %>%
  select(member_casual, started_at, ended_at) %>%
  mutate(ride_length = difftime(ended_at, started_at, units = "mins"))

member_feb <- new_data_feb %>% 
  filter(member_casual == "member") %>%
  summarise(mean_member_feb = mean(ride_length),sum_member_feb = sum(ride_length))

casual_feb <- new_data_feb %>% 
  filter(member_casual == "casual") %>%
  summarise(mean_casual_feb = mean(ride_length),sum_casual_feb = sum(ride_length))
```

But, I feel this is not right because programming suppose to help the user get through repetition work. How can I repeat these steps through code?

Comment: I would try [writing a function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/doc/manual/R-intro.html#Writing-your-own-functions).

Comment: You can also combine all 12 CSVs into one dataframe and then use grouping/reshaping operations. That's probably the more "standard" approach to data analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I already combine all 12 CSVs, and now I am stuck at how to separate summaries of 12 months in my data

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a list of the CSV:

`files_list <- list.files('~/directory/', pattern = '*.csv')`

Then read all the files:

`df_list <- lapply(files_list, read.csv)`

Now you have all file contents in a single object. From there you could `bind_rows` or similar to combine everything into a single data frame, or work on them as individual elements in a list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I can combine all data into a data frame, but I am stuck at how to separate summaries for 12 months, do you have any idea, if any, please help, thanks. this is my code: 
``` 
total_list <- bind_rows(df_list)

df_info <- total_list %>% 
  mutate(ride_length = difftime(ended_at, started_at, units = "mins")) %>% 
  group_by(member_casual)|> 
  summarize(mean_m = mean(ride_length), sum_m = sum(ride_length), points_m = n())
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work

```r
library(dplyr)
file_list <- sprintf("2022%02d-divvy-tripdata.csv", 1:12)

extract_info <- function(file_name) {
  n_month <- as.integer(substr(file_name, 5, 6))
  df <- read.csv(file_name)
  df_info <- df |> 
    mutate(ride_length = difftime(ended_at, started_at, units = "mins")) |> 
    group_by(member_casual) |> 
    summarize(mean_m = mean(ride_length), sum_m = sum(ride_length), points_m = n()) |> 
    mutate(month = month.abb[n_month]) |> 
    ungroup()
  return(df_info)
}

all_list <- lapply(file_list, extract_info)
all_info <- do.call(rbind, all_list)
```

I've tested the code generating fake data as follows

```
set.seed(1023)
generate_content <- function(file_name, ini_time = Sys.time(), n = 10){
  types <- c("member", "casual")
  seq_start_time <- ini_time + 3600 * (0:(24 * 5 - 1))
  started_at <- sample(seq_start_time, n)
  ended_at <- started_at + 60 * sample(1:15, n, replace = TRUE)
  member_casual <- types[sample(1:2, n, replace = TRUE)]
  df <- data.frame(member_casual, started_at, ended_at)
  write.csv(df, file_name)
  return(TRUE)  
}

sapply(file_list, generate_content)
```

and the result reads as

```
head(all_info)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   member_casual mean_m         sum_m   points_m month
#>   <chr>         <drtn>         <drtn>     <int> <chr>
#> 1 casual         5.000000 mins 15 mins        3 Jan  
#> 2 member         9.857143 mins 69 mins        7 Jan  
#> 3 casual        10.166667 mins 61 mins        6 Feb  
#> 4 member         7.000000 mins 28 mins        4 Feb  
#> 5 casual         8.800000 mins 44 mins        5 Mar  
#> 6 member         9.400000 mins 47 mins        5 Mar
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Sir, your code works nicely with my data. Currently, my work is not related programming or data analytics, I just start to learn how to analyze data and mostly I don't know how to begin and don't understand how people do, do you have any recommendation about what books to read or what thing to learn, I want to learn from basic and fundamentality, if you have any idea, please list out.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following :

```
#list of object names

MT <-      c("jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sept","oct","nov","dec")
MN <- c("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12")

for(cpt in 1:length(MT)){   
       data_ = read.csv(paste0("2022",MN[cpt],"-divvy-tripdata.csv")) #call csv name

  #execute your script

  new_data_ <- data %>%
    select(member_casual, started_at, ended_at) %>%
    mutate(ride_length = difftime(ended_at, started_at, units = "mins"))


  member_ <- new_data_ %>% 
    filter(member_casual == "member") %>%
    summarise(mean_member_ = mean(ride_length),sum_member_ = sum(ride_length))



  casual_ <- new_data_ %>% 
    filter(member_casual == "casual") %>%
    summarise(mean_casual_ = mean(ride_length),sum_casual_ = sum(ride_length))

  #assign values

  assign(paste0("data_",MT[cpt]),value = data_)
  assign(paste0("new_data_",MT[cpt]),value = new_data_)
  assign(paste0("member_",MT[cpt]),value = member_)
  assign(paste0("casual_",MT[cpt]),value = casual_)

}
```

Extra remark :

paste(x,y,z) will display the strings as : "x y z" whereas paste0(x,y,z) will display them as "xyz"